# можно ли как то через env указать в какой директории искать файлы для "volumes"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

в windows-linux-envirinment почему то докер не хочет понимать в какой директории я его запускаю, в итоге пути типа ./somefile он не понимает и требует полного пути типа /host_mnt/c/dir/dir/dir/filename.
но так в репу я это залить не могу так как прод хост не виндус и там таких путей нет. собственно там они и не нужны, там все и без полных путей прекрасно работает.

так вот можно ли как то через env указать в какой директории искать файлы для "volumes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю как в windows но в linux получилось

```
$ WIN_PATH=/path/ docker-compose run --rm <service_name> bash
```

в docker-compose.yaml прописано следующие

```
volumes:
- ${WIN_PATH}./somefile:/somefile
```

Если переменная WIN_PATH не заданна то docker бросит сообщение

> WARNING: The WIN_PATH variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank
>   string.

Comment: да супер работает. только я еще для удобства эту переменную в .env файле прописал. собственно я такое и сам пробовал, только кто же знал что в этом файле такой синтаксис для вывода переменной